# Sql Server Reporting Servicess. Is there a way to tell a Table control not to display some rows in the Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Instead of filtering the data filtered  on the query, is there a way to tell report generator not to display some rows in a table.  Example have something like display row if [id]>5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on the row itself, there is a "Hidden" property, so you would set an "expression" on that row filtering for any ID <= 5 (remember, it's a "hidden" property, not a "shown" property)